# How to UITableView & UICollectionView link vertical scroll and UICollectionView & anotherView link horizontal scroll, like a SpreadSheet iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a problem with the creation of the layout shown in the picture.
Does anyone know how can I create it.
I want to link left tableview's (only vertical scroll enabled) horizontal scrolling with collection's view horizontal scrolling, and create scale view (only horizontal scroll enabled) horizontal scroll linked with collectionView horizontal scroll.
I know it is a bit chaotic, but I think that diagram best represents my problem.
I would also like to load collectionview's data in real time while scrolling.
At the end I will add that I am using the storyboard in my app.

[Link to my schema picture](http://img716.imageshack.us/img716/3623/klho.png)

Comment: I just found two libraries that fully corresponds to what I was looking for! 
[NGVaryingGridView](https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGVaryingGridView)
and
[SMGridView](https://github.com/brewster/SMGridView)

Comment: However, these libraries do not work as I wanted it to. Does anyone have idea?